# Django Installed Apps Location

Tags: python, django

I am an experienced PHP programmer using Django for the first time, and I think it is incredible!

I have a project that has a lot of apps, so I wanted to group them in an apps folder.

So the structure of the project is:

```
/project/
/project/apps/
/project/apps/app1/
/project/apps/app2
```

Then in Django settings I have put this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'project.apps.app1',
    'project.apps.app2',
)
```

This does not seem to work?

Any ideas on how you can put all your apps into a seprate folder and not in the project root?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you using PYTHONPATH?  If so, please provide that value, also.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Make sure that the '__init__.py' file is in your apps directory, if it's not there it won't be recognized as part of the package.

So each of the folders here should have '__init__.py' file in it. (empty is fine).

```
/project/
/project/apps/
/project/apps/app1/
/project/apps/app2
```

Then as long as your root 'module' folder is in your PYTHONPATH you'll be able to import from your apps.

Here's the documentation regarding the python search path for your reading pleasure:

http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path

And a nice simple explanation of what __init__.py file is for:

http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-is-init-py-used-for.htm

Comment: If any of these apps are generic enough to be possibly reusable (and it's a good idea to make them so if you can), you can save yourself headache by placing them in a path location that doesn't tie them to the project.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your apps are in your PYTHONPATH, everything should work. Try setting that environment variable to the folder containing your apps.

```
PYTHONPATH="/path/to/your/apps/dir/:$PYTHONPATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your top-level `urls.py` (also named in your `settings.py`) must be able to use a simple "import" statement to get your applications.

Does `import project.apps.app1.urls` work?  If not, then your `PYTHONPATH` isn't set up properly, or you didn't install your project in Python's `site-packages` directory.

I suggest using the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, instead of installing into site-packages.  Django applications (to me, anyway) seem easier to manage when outside site-packages.

We do the following:

- Django projects go in `/opt/project/`.
- `PYTHONPATH` includes `/opt/project`.
- Our `settings.py` uses `apps.this` and `apps.that` (note that the `project` part of the name is part of the `PYTHONPATH`, not part of the import.