# Why doesn't "manage.py sqlall" see my app?

Tags: django

Under what circumstances could an app be visible as installed to the syncdb and through the shell django.conf.settings.INSTALLED_APPS, but not the sqlall command?

Below i've pasted my terminal output, which shows the confusing situation.

```
$ manage.py syncdb
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
No fixtures found.

Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > django.contrib.admin
 > django.contrib.admindocs
 > django.contrib.gis
 > south
 > django_extensions
 > debug_toolbar
 > django_countries
 > myapp.apps.core

Not synced (use migrations):
 - tastypie
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
$ manage.py shell

In [1]: from django.conf import settings

In [2]: settings.INSTALLED_APPS
Out[2]:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django.contrib.gis',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'south',
 'django_extensions',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'tastypie',
 'django_countries',
 'django_nose',
 'myapp.apps.core',
 'myapp.apps.mobile',
 'myapp.apps.api']

In [3]:
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)? y
$ manage.py sqlall myapp.apps.core
Error: App with label myapp.apps.core could not be found. Are you sure your INSTALLED_APPS setting is correct?
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you out: [Django Installed Apps Location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511291/django-installed-apps-location)

Comment: those suggestions didn't help. in any case, the app works, it just isn't seen somehow by sqlall ...

Comment: Try importing your app's models on the Django shell. I had similar issues once and that at least gave me further information on what was wrong (I think it was problems importing some 3rd party library).